# Polymorphism and Overloading

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I recently encountered the following scenario:

I have a superclass A and a class B deriving from it. A function, say oracle, returns an object of either type. I want to do different things depending on the type but I can't introduce new member function for A and B.

One solution would be to branch according to getClass().getName(). However, I was wondering whether polymorphism can achieve the same behavior using overloading:

```
public class Main
{
    static class A{}
    static class B extends A{}

    public static void foo(A a) { System.out.println("A"); };
    public static void foo(B b) { System.out.println("B"); };

    static A oracle()
    {
        return (Math.random() > 0.5) ? new A() : new B();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A x = oracle();
        foo(x);
    }
}
```

This always outputs "A" and my suspicion is that this is due to early binding used to resolve function calls. Can someone acknowledge this?

Comment: You're passing it a variable of type `A`, so it calls the method whose signature takes `A`. I think the only way would be using `getClass().getName()` as you mentioned.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I would write that down as a solution (a bit more verbosely, perhaps).

Comment: Exactly. If you absolutely must, you may use the `instanceof` operator to switch on the actual objects type. But it is better OO-Design to put `foo()` inside the classes A and B (so the objects know what to "say")

Comment: But the object _knows_ it's type and if I'd call a member function that B overrides, it would work.

Comment: You could try to cast to B and if that throws an exception it is an A ... smelly :( Guess here isn't really a "beautiful" solution without being able to add member functions to A and B.

Comment: The object knows its type, but the method it's passed to does not (without `getClass().getName()`/`instanceof`/reflection); methods only know the type of the variable passed to them.

Comment: It sounds like you have to fix a problem caused by someone else's code without changing their code. Frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In technical terms, Java is a *single-dispatch* OOP language. What that means is that the runtime decision which method to call (*method dispatch*) only takes into account the first method argument—the one to the left of the dot. There you can see how this principle is so deeply ingrained into the language that the first argument even gets special syntactic treatment.

Therefore, no, you can't accomplish runtime polymorphism with overloading.

Answer (score 2):

This article give a good explanation of what is happening:  [Overloading is compile-time binding](http://skeletoncoder.blogspot.com/2006/09/java-tutorials-overloading-is-compile.html)

I think what you are going to have to do is implement `instanceof` code in you `foo` method
to treat each type differently.

In regards to your `getClass().getName()` assertion, you should NEVER do this. That is what `instanceof` is for. Work from more specific to less specific (ie. start with B then A).

Comment: Okay, I think that summarizes well what many here have said. If possible, having member functions in `A` and `B` would be more elegant and otherwise `instanceof` is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `foo(A a)` is the function with exactly the same method signature, so it will use that one.

In this case `foo(B b)` is never a valid option as you would need to do reflection to realize it might be an appropriate method.  Java will not use reflection on all parameters just to see if a method might eventually match, it would just be too time consuming.

If you want different methods to be called, then you should use Class inheritance or other polymorphic techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your foo methods as instance methods within the A and B classes. then calling in your case x.foo() with an instance of a B object should give you the result "B".

Comment: OP said that was not an option

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
static class A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    A x = oracle();
    x.foo();
}
```

Member functions know the type which they are a member of.

Comment: "[...] but I can't introduce new member function for A and B"

Comment: Just what i was about to write :) +1

Comment: OP has said this is not an option

Comment: I know this works but I can't introduce member classes as explained above.

Comment: what about `extend`ing a class?